# Serializer.data not evaluating queryset in tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have such serializer

```
class ActResultSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    actions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_actions(self, obj):
        return Actions.objects.filter(type='solution').values_list('code', flat=True)
```

Here is my test case

```
def test_return_to_provider(self):
    response = self.client.get('/acts/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    queryset = Act.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    self.assertEqual(
        len(response.data),
        queryset.count()
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.data, ActResultSerializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```

The problem is, that last `assertEqual` fails, because serializer data returns `('actions', <QuerySet []>)`. How can I evaluate that QuerySet to compare response and serializer datas?

Comment: Django tests the views with a *separate* database, so there are likely no elements in the test database, and therefore the data is empty.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I'm not complaining about empty queryset, but about test fails. If I add `list()` to `get_actions`, last `assertEqual` will pass and serializer returns `('actions', [])`. Guess this is because queryset is not evaluating without list

Comment: @Headmasters: it evaluates the `QuerySet`, that is the `[]` part in the queryset, but since you do not explain how to convert it to a primitive type, it will convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_actions` returns an *empty* `QuerySet`, not a list, so it will convert it to a string. You can use `list(…)` to convert it to a list of strings:

```
def get_actions(self, obj):
    return list(
        Actions.objects.filter(type='solution').values_list('code', flat=True)
    )
```

Comment: @Headmaster: no, this happens for any queryset. There is a difference between a `QuerySet` that contains data, or a list. A `.values_list(..)` although the name might indicate otherwise, is still a `QuerySet`.